# Migrate to Australia Under Section 189(Skill Independant)

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, australia, pr

I am planning to migrate to Australia and applying for Skill Independent Sub-Class 189. 
I have done my BE in Electrical and Electronics Engineering but have Three Years plus more experience  in Software Field(Senior Software Engineer). I want to know if I apply for my Skill assessment through ACS will it be Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You will get points for your work experience but not your diploma or you could apply as one of 'skills' that would accept you diploma but not work experience...

For Batchelor you get 15 points while for 3 years programming (if you can provide references) only 5, so....